# How to space the children of a div with css?

Tags: css

I want a gap of say 30px; between all children of my div. E.g if I have:

```
<div id="parent">    
   <img ... />
   <p>...</p>
   <div>.......</div>
</div>
```

I want all of them to have a space of 30px; between them. How can I do this with CSS?

Comment: 30px space from all sides of the elements

Answer (score 185, accepted):

For an unknown amount of children you could use.

```
#parent > * {
    margin: 30px 0;
}
```

This will add a top and bottom margin of 30px to all direct children of `#parent`.

But `img` is not displaying as block default, so you may use:

```
#parent > * {
    display: block;
    margin: 30px 0;
}
```

Vertical margins of block elements will be collapsed. But you will have margins at top and bottom of your parent div. To avoid that use the following code:

```
#parent > * {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#parent > *:first-child {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

This will only add top margin and removes that top margin for the first element.

Comment: So the paddings will be applied to all descendants, not only childrens.

Comment: I was editing my post the time you commented and added the ">" direct child selector.

Comment: See Topiq's answer for a shorter solution. To understand the difference between the two selectors, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12289888/1461929

Answer (score 28):

The following css will work well

```
div > *:not(:last-child) {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 30px; 
}
```

`>` selects all elements that are direct children of the `div` (so you don't get weird inner spacing issues), and adds a bottom margin to all that aren't the last child, using `:not(:last-child)` (so you don't get a trailing space).

`display: block` makes sure all elements are displayed as blocks (occupying their own lines), which `img`s aren't by default.

Comment: Please provide an explanation as to why this is a solution to OP's problem. Code only answers are discouraged on SO as they do not help OP or future visitors of the site.

Comment: Best answer here. This post better explains the difference to the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12289888/1461929

Answer (score 18):

You can easily do that with:

```
#parent > * + * {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

This will be applied to all direct children except the first one, so you can think of it as a *gap* between elements.

Answer (score 9):

Probably the easiest way is this:

```
#parent * {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

or

```
#parent * {
  margin: 15px 0;
}
```

Keep in mind, though, that this will get *everything* in `#parent`, including things inside the `p` and `div` tags. If you want just the direct children, you can use `#parent > *` (this is call the direct descendent selector) instead.

Keep in mind, `<img>` is an inline element by default, so you might need to do:

```
#parent img {
  display: block;
}
```

for it to use the margins.

Answer (score 9):

Use CSS `gap` property.

```css
.parent_class_name{
  gap: 30px;
}
```

The above CSS code will apply a gap/separation of `30px` between children of the `parent_class_name` class.

Example: This code will apply `1rem` gap between element (rows and columns).

```html
<div class="gap_container">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
</div>
```

```css
.gap_container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
}
```

> The gap property defines the size of the gap between the rows and columns. It is a shorthand for the following properties:
>
> - row-gap
> - column-gap

Apply `row` and `column` values separately.
`gap: row-value column-value;`

Learn more: [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_gap.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Create a CSS class for them with code:

```
.BottomMargin
{
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

And assign this class to `parent`'s children using jQuery or manually like this:

```
<div id="parent">    
    <img class="BottomMargin" ... />
    <p class="BottomMargin">...</p>
    <div>.......</div>
</div>
```

the last one may not have one and this is also doable using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it by CSS standarts:

```
div > *{
   margin-top:30px;
}
```

More info could be found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors

Answer (score 0):

Just put a top and bottom margin of 30px on your `p` element:

```
p { margin: 30px 0 30px 0; }
```

Note: the above will add this margin to *all* your p elements. To restrict to just this one, either add an inline style attribute:

```
<p style="margin: 30px 0 30px 0;">...</p>
```

or better use a class:

```
<p class="mypara">...</p>
```

and in css:

```
p.para { margin: 30px 0 30px 0; }
```

Btw, the notation here for margin is:

```
margin: top right bottom left;
```

Or you can individually specify top and bottom margins:

```
margin-top: 30px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
```

So you could have a class like this:

```
.bord { margin-bottom: 30px; }
```

and add this class to every element you want to have a margin-bottom of 30px:

```
<div class="bord">....</div>
```

Comment: I think he wants all of the elements in the parent to have a 30px margin, not just the paragraph.

Comment: Richard meant that the code he gave will actually give the OP what he wanted, but maybe the OP just put those 3 elements as a piece of markup and it may contain more than 3 children.

Comment: why another class if you could select the paragraph by its parent id

Answer (score -1):

Surest way is to add a class to all of the internal elements with the exception of the last one.

```
<style>
.margin30 {
   margin-bottom: 30px;
}
<div id="parent">    
  <img class="margin30" ... />
  <p class="margin30">...</p>
  <div>.......</div>
</div>
```

This way, additional elements can just be tagged with the class. Remember that you can multiclass style elements by separating them within the class value in the tag with spaces, like so:

```
<img class="margin30 bigimage" ... />
```

Finally, you can attach the classes dynamically with Javascript (code off the top of my head, not tested, no sanity checks or error handling, ymmv etc.):

```
function addSpace(elementId) {
   children = document.getElementById(elementId).childNodes;
   for (i=0;i<(children.length - 1);i++)
      children[i].className = "margin30 " + children[i].className;
}
```