# How can I use a not:first-child selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have `div` tag containing several `ul` tags.

If I trying set CSS properties only for the first `ul` tag, and this code works:

```css
div ul:first-child {
    background-color: #900;
}
```

When I want set CSS properties for each `ul` tag except the first, I tried this:

```css
div ul:not:first-child {
    background-color: #900;
}
```

also this:

```css
div ul:not(:first-child) {
    background-color: #900;
}
```

and this:

```css
div ul:first-child:after {
    background-color: #900;
}
```

But to no effect. How must I write in CSS: "each element, except the first"?

Comment: Check these references :[link](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html%23id-selectors), [link](https://web.dev/learn/css/selectors/)

Answer (score 1904, accepted):

One of the versions you posted [actually works](http://jsfiddle.net/5TKjB/) for all modern browsers (where [CSS selectors level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) are [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)):

```
div ul:not(:first-child) {
    background-color: #900;
}
```

If you need to support legacy browsers, or if you are hindered by the `:not` selector's [limitation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) (it only accepts a [simple selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) as an argument) then you can use another technique:

Define a rule that has greater scope than what you intend and then "revoke" it conditionally, limiting its scope to what you do intend:

```
div ul {
    background-color: #900;  /* applies to every ul */
}

div ul:first-child {
    background-color: transparent; /* limits the scope of the previous rule */
}
```

When limiting the scope use the [default value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background-properties) for each CSS attribute that you are setting.

Comment: do you know exactly which versions this isn't supported on?

Comment: @Simon_Weaver: In practice everything but IE < 9 supports it. A great resource to get this kind of information is http://caniuse.com.

Comment: Hmm.. watch out for the the restrictions of the first solution: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-not-sel-list The second one sounded more reasonable for me. Thanks!

Comment: @iorrah your caniuse link is for a list of selectors, and yes, support is very limited still.  The OP is not using a list of selectors. So I think [https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) is more appropriate with great support beyond the days of IE8.

Comment: This works even without the div element at the start in chrome.

Comment: I used this idea to do some CSS gymnastics and make the first value on a select box the "Placeholder" if you will. `select:invalid {
    color: #cacaca;
}

select:invalid :not(:first-child){
    color: initial;
}
`

Comment: @Jon it's not working in my case,    
.booking_child > div:not(:first-child) {
    width: 33.33%;
}

Answer (score 183):

This CSS2 solution ("any `ul` after another `ul`") works, too, and is supported by more browsers.

```
div ul + ul {
  background-color: #900;
}
```

Unlike `:not` and `:nth-sibling`, the [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) is supported by IE7+.

If you have **JavaScript** changes these properties after the page loads, you should look at some known bugs in the **IE7** and **IE8** implementations of this.  [See this link](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/).

For any static web page, this should work perfectly.

Comment: @Leven:  That [quirksmode link](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/) says it should work in IE7, but only statically.  If your JS places another element in front of it, it might not be updated correctly.  Is that the issue you saw?

Comment: might be worth noting that in a sequence of elements like: `ul ul div ul` (where these elements are siblings), only the second ul will be selected, since the last one does not have a `ul` previous to itself

Answer (score 99):

Since `:not` is not accepted by **IE6-8**, I would suggest you this:

```
div ul:nth-child(n+2) {
    background-color: #900;
}
```

So you pick every `ul` in its parent element *except the first one*.

Refer to Chris Coyer's **["Useful :nth-child Recipes"](http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/)** article for more `nth-child` [examples](http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/).

Comment: who actually still uses IE6-8 in 2019?

Comment: Considering the answer was from 2013?

Comment: just curious why is this answer not getting more votes since it also cover legacy browser and looks more straight forward to me, is there any potential pitfall in using this?  tks

Comment: Creativity is a beautiful thing and this question and its answers are something for the ages.

Answer (score 48):

You can use "first-child" pseudo-class inside the "not()" pseudo-class.

```css
div ul:not(:first-child){
    background-color: #900;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pseudo Classes</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternative ways,

1. With "nth-child()", It will select nth number of child.

```css
div ul:not(:nth-child(1)){
    background-color: #900;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pseudo Classes</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

2. With "nth-of-type()", It will select nth number of element of its
   parent.

   ```css
   div ul:not(:nth-of-type(1)){
       background-color: #900;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <html>
     <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <title>Pseudo Classes</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div>
       <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
       </ul>
       <ul>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
       <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
       </ul>
       <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. With "nth-last-child()", It will select nth number of child counting from the last child. If you have 4 "ul" tags, you can write like this.

```css
div ul:not(:nth-last-child(4)){
    background-color: #900;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pseudo Classes</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

4. With "nth-last-of-type()", It will select nth number of element of its parent counting from the last child. If you have 4 "ul" tags, you can write like this.

```css
div ul:not(:nth-last-of-type(4)){
    background-color: #900;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pseudo Classes</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

These are some of the best ways to handle these kind of situations.

Answer (score 27):

`not(:first-child)` does not seem to work anymore. At least with the more recent versions of Chrome and Firefox.

Instead, try this:

```
ul:not(:first-of-type) {}
```

Comment: They both work, but they have different meaning. `ul:not(:first-child)` means literally "any `ul` element that is not first child of its parent", so it won't match even the 1st `ul` if it's preceded by another element (`p`, heading etc.). On the contrary, `ul:not(:first-of-type)` means "any `ul` element except the 1st `ul` in the container". You are right that OP probably needed the latter behavior, but your explanation is rather misleading.

Answer (score 22):

```
div li~li {
    color: red;
}
```

Supports IE7

Answer (score 16):

You can use any selector with `not`

```
p:not(:first-child){}
p:not(:first-of-type){}
p:not(:checked){}
p:not(:last-child){}
p:not(:last-of-type){}
p:not(:first-of-type){}
p:not(:nth-last-of-type(2)){}
p:not(nth-last-child(2)){}
p:not(:nth-child(2)){}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use your selector with `:not` like bellow you can use any selector inside the `:not()`

```
any_CSS_selector:not(any_other_CSS_selector):not(any_other_CSS_selector){
    /*YOUR STYLE*/
}
```

you can use `:not` without parent selector as well.

```
   :not(:nth-child(2)){
        /*YOUR STYLE*/
   }
```

More examples

```
any_CSS_selector:not(:first-child){
    /*YOUR STYLE*/
}
any_CSS_selector:not(:first-of-type){
    /*YOUR STYLE*/
}
any_CSS_selector:not(:checked){
    /*YOUR STYLE*/
}
any_CSS_selector:not(:last-child){
    /*YOUR STYLE*/
}
any_CSS_selector:not(:last-of-type){
    /*YOUR STYLE*/
}
any_CSS_selector:not(:first-of-type){
    /*YOUR STYLE*/
}
any_CSS_selector:not(:nth-last-of-type(2)){
    /*YOUR STYLE*/
}
any_CSS_selector:not(:nth-last-child(2)){
    /*YOUR STYLE*/
}
any_CSS_selector:not(:nth-child(2)){
    /*YOUR STYLE*/
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I didn't have luck with some of the above,

This was the only one that actually worked for me

`ul:not(:first-of-type) {}`

This worked for me when I was trying to have the first button displayed on the page not be effected by a margin-left option.

this was the option I tried first but it didn't work

`ul:not(:first-child)`

Answer (score 2):

As I used `ul:not(:first-child)` is a perfect solution.

```
div ul:not(:first-child) {
    background-color: #900;
}
```

Why is this a perfect because by using `ul:not(:first-child)`, we can apply CSS on inner elements. Like `li, img, span, a` tags etc.

But when used others solutions:

```
div ul + ul {
  background-color: #900;
}
```

and

```
div li~li {
    color: red;
}
```

and

```
ul:not(:first-of-type) {}
```

and

```
div ul:nth-child(n+2) {
    background-color: #900;
}
```

These restrict only ul level CSS. Suppose we cannot apply CSS on `li` as `div ul + ul li'.

**For inner level elements the first Solution works perfectly.**

```
div ul:not(:first-child) li{
        background-color: #900;
    }
```

and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

```
li + li {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to change the background color of the element placed AFTER your basic "ul" - elements, except the first one:

See [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) documentation for more details on how this works.

```
div ul:nth-child(n+2)::after {
    background-color: #900;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
div ul::nth-child(n+2){
    background-color: #900;
}
```

Is working too