# Selector for all but first of class

Tags: css

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="img"></li>        
    <li></li>
    <li class="img"></li>        
    <li class="img"></li>        
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
 list-style-type: none;   
}

li {
    background-color: red;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
}

li.img:not(:first-child) {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Result:

http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/K3ZnA/

I want all but the first `li.img` to have a blue background.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You cannot do this with `:not(:first-child)` because all `li.img` elements except the first `li` (no matter if it's `.img` or not) are indeed not the first child of their parent. So that selector would exclude the first `li.img` only if it were the first `li` without qualification.

However, you can do it with the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) `~`:

```
li.img ~ li.img {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

This selector matches any `li.img` that is the sibling of any other `li.img` but appears after it in document order, or in other words every `li.img` but the first.

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/rbfdn/)**, and be aware that IE < 9 does not support this selector.

Comment: This does work for IE7 and 8.  I've spaced some input fields using the selector.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to make a working selector similar to `.img:not(.img~.img)` (this doesn't work) to select only the first-of-class? https://jsfiddle.net/oriadam/27cfmbpp/

Comment: @oriadam off the top probably use the technique in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289853/css-notfirst-child-selector/12289888#12289888): `.img` to set the property value you want for the first-of-class, then `.img ~ .img` to reset it back to previous value for everything except first-of-class.

Comment: Thanks @Jon - I cannot use that technique because I'm selecting elements with `querySelectorAll`, not setting a css property. I need to select the first of each class, something like that: `#element1,.class1:first,class2:first,class3:first`.
I can use JS to split the query with ',' and then combine several `querySelector` (not all) but it's ugly and slows down the code.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to select all other li.img and give them a different backgroundColor:

```
li.img ~ li.img {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

May be, you could add a javascript like in case IE 8 (and older) or such browser does not support ~ selector as told by Jon above:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("img")[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
```