# Can't get hasClass to work properly with condition

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to wrap my head around this: http://jsfiddle.net/pvyaL/

```
    $(function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $('.navigation li').hover(function () {
                $(this).find('a').attr('class', 'hovering');
            },
            function () {
                $(this).find('a').attr('class', '');
            });
        };
    });
```

Basically what I want, is to ignore the hover class change, if the element already has a specific class (in this case; 'selected').

What am I missing?

Comment: 'this' refers here to document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this)` is in your code 'nothing', look at http://jsfiddle.net/pvyaL/2/

I also changed this:

```
if (!$(this).find('a').hasClass('selected')) {
```

So the check is on the `<a>`, not on the `<li>`

Comment: `this` always refer to something. in this particular case it's the `document`

Answer (score 3):

That code has several mistakes:

- `this` refers to the document, not on any `li` element.
- Setting classes with `.attr` is a really bad choice -- `addClass`, `removeClass` and `toggleClass` exist exactly for this purpose.
- You do not even need jQuery for this, as it can be done with pure CSS.

In jQuery form, what you want is more like

```
$('.navigation li:not(.selected)').hover(
function () {
    $(this).find('a').addClass('hovering');
},
function () {
    $(this).find('a').removeClass('hovering');
});
```

If you want to make the script respond to changes in the `selected` class dynamically another version would be the solution:

```
$('.navigation li').hover(
function () {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')) $(this).find('a').addClass('hovering');
},
function () {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')) $(this).find('a').removeClass('hovering');
});
```

Of course there is no reason to do this with jQuery; pure CSS will suffice:

```
.navigation li:not(.selected):hover a {
    /* your styles go here */
}
```

The `:not` selector is not supported by IE8, but if that is a problem you can work around it using the [set/revoke trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289853/css-notfirst-child-selector/12289888#12289888).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however I need to do more than just CSS. But I'll keep in mind when to use what and what not. Again, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function() {
    $('.navigation').on('mouseenter', 'li:not(.selected)', function() {
        $(this).find('a').attr('class', 'hovering');
    }).on('mouseleave', 'li:not(.selected)', function() {
        $(this).find('a').attr('class', '');
    })
});
```

or

```
$(function() {
    $('.navigation li').hover(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).find('a').attr('class', 'hovering');
        }
    }, function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).find('a').attr('class', '');
        }
    });
});
```