# Hide all except first child of an element using pure css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to hide every other child after first child of classa class element.

```css
div.classa {
    display:none;
}
div.classa:first-child {
    display:block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <h3>abc</h3>
    <div class="classa">some content</div>
    <h3>xyz</h3>
    <div class="classa">more content</div>
    <h3>header3</h3>
    <div class="classa">another content</div>
</div>
```

How to achieve this using pure css.

Comment: whether you want to show first '<h3>' or '<div class="classa">'

Comment: be precise about what you want to show.

Comment: I want to show first  '<div class="classa">'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to [support IE8](http://caniuse.com/#search=general%20sibling), then your only option is [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors):

```css
div.classa ~ .classa {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <h3>abc</h3>
    <div class="classa">some content</div>
    <h3>xyz</h3>
    <div class="classa">more content</div>
    <h3>header3</h3>
    <div class="classa">another content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 50):

Check out here https://jsfiddle.net/32vw04jg/1/

```
<div class="content">
  <div>
    <h3>abc</h3>
    <div class="classa">some content</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>xyz</h3>
    <div class="classa">more content</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>header3</h3>
    <div class="classa">another content</div>
  </div>
</div>


.content > div:not(:first-child) {
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

The problem in your code is that you want to hide the *first* `.classa`, but the first `.classa` isn't the first child in `.content`, the `h3` is the first child.

So as an alternative to the `:not()` pseudo class, you could use `nth-of-type(n+2)`. It will select all elements with the same type, except the first one.

```css
div.classa:nth-of-type(n+2) {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <h3>abc</h3>
    <div class="classa">some content</div>
    <h3>xyz</h3>
    <div class="classa">more content</div>
    <h3>header3</h3>
    <div class="classa">another content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like that:

```
<div class="content">
    <h3>abc</h3>
    <div class="classa">some content1</div>
    <h3>xyz</h3>
    <div class="classa">more content2</div>
    <h3>header3</h3>
    <div class="classa">another content3</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.content > .classa:not(:nth-of-type(2)) {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But it seems this code isn't working, even on firefox - am I doing something wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/32vw04jg/

Answer (score 2):

There is new CSS3's `:first-of-type` for your case:
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/fpo11Lts/)

```
.content h3, .content div{
    display:none;
}
.content .classa:first-of-type{  
    display : block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I can understand correctly the question the goal here is to hide every child (`h3` and `div.classa`) with the exception of the first `h3` and the `div.classa` next to it.

The easiest way to accomplish it is a combination of the `:first-of-type` and the `~` (general siblings) selectors.

```css
div.classa:first-of-type ~ * { display:none; }
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <h3>abc</h3>
    <div class="classa">some content</div>
    <h3>xyz</h3>
    <div class="classa">more content</div>
    <h3>header3</h3>
    <div class="classa">another content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `:not` pseudo class — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289853/css-notfirst-child-selector)

Comment: Thanks. Any alternative to support ie8?

Answer (score -2):

```
.content > *{ display: none;}
.content > *:first-child{ display: block !important; }
```