# CSS: is "not a first child" selector possible?

Tags: css, css-selectors, children

Does CSS make possible selecting all the child elements except a first child?

Comment: Maybe duplicate to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289853/css-notfirst-child-selector

Comment: Please don't deface your question.

Comment: @Paul: because it's against the rules of Stack Overflow. It wasn't a mistake, it's just a duplicate question. *"I won't accept answers here"* - do you seriously expect people to help you in the future?

Comment: @Paul: you can ask moderators/high reputation users to delete your question, but it's not necessary to deface it.

Comment: @vaultah: I asked them. No reaction. You are right that you deserved your upvote and answer flag. Sorry. But I really do not understand why to keep answers to the duplicate question. A duplicate question should be a kind of redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)[`(:first-child)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)

```
parent child:not(:first-child) { /* style */ }
```

Example:

```css
div span:not(:first-child) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>A</span>
    <span>B</span>
    <span>C</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the :nth-child selector:

```
:nth-child(n+2) {}
```

It will select all children starting with the second one. Or, if all children have the same class (or element tag) you can also use

```
#parent .class + .class {}
#parent div + div {}
```

Comment: That should be n+2, as n starts counting from 0 which will result in n+1=1, matching the first child.

Comment: @BoltClock Of course, thanks for spotting the mistake, it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `div:not(:first-child)`.