# How to exclude the first item in a flexbox wrap?

Tags: css, flexbox

Is there a way to exclude the first item in a flex wrap other than reorder the markup?

```
<div class="container">    
  <div id="tobeexcluded">abc</div>
  <div class="flexitem">content</div>
  <div class="flexitem">content</div>
  <div class="flexitem">content</div>
</div>
```

EDIT:
I've tried now

```
:not(:first-child)
```

and also

```
:not(#tobeexcluded)
```

but it's not working. This is the actual class construction, it's a drupal view:

```
.view-id-reference_list .view-content:not(:first-child) {
display: flex
flex-flow: wrap
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m62090za/4/

Here's what i want: https://jsfiddle.net/Lxhpwqzn/1/ but without changing the markup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css not:first-child selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289853/css-notfirst-child-selector)

Comment: are your serious or sleepy? this is not at all duplicate for the link you given

Comment: You could exclude it using css `#tobeexcluded { display: none }`.

Comment: I don't want to hide it, it should be removed from the flexbox wrap.

Comment: As you can see in the fiddle, the flexbox wrap isn't working anymore when i add :not(:first-child) to the div. The filter-div should be above the flex-flow...

Answer (score 71, accepted):

> Is there a way to exclude the first item in a flex wrap other than reorder the markup?

After some initial confusion we now understand that what is actually required is for the content to wrap *after* the first div.

Obviously, the simplest method to achieve this is for the first div to be 100% wide of the parent.

```css
.view-container .view-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.filterbox {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="view-container">
  <div class="view-content">
    <div class="filterbox">FILTER</div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      Flex-ITEM
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      Flex-ITEM
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      Flex-ITEM
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I read this, thought it wasn't what I was looking for (cause it was so simple), closed the tab, realized the beauty of it, and reopened it again.