# Excluding child element from flex container

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, centering

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"><img /></div>
  <div class="image"><img /></div>
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

I have this situation. I need to center two images into the container but i need to display the "text" in a new line under the two images.
I did it with css

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flexwrap: wrap;
}

.image {
  display: inline-block
}
```

Text goes to new line but up to a certain resolution. How can exclude text from flex flow?

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36470038/how-to-exclude-the-first-item-in-a-flexbox-wrap

Answer (score 3):

Set the width of the text to `100%`, and align the text to the center:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.text {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"><img src="https://picsum.photos/120/80?1"></div>
  <div class="image"><img src="https://picsum.photos/120/80?2"></div>
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
```