# css grid template column elementor make 2 / 1

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor, dynamic-columns

I want to make ordering as on my photo.
I maded blog page with elementor and need to change with css grid template column.

Code is:

```
   .elementor-grid-2 .elementor-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1,1fr);
}
```

[image]

I want to make first appear 2 on 1 like photo :)
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: First thing is to note that you need TWO columns, not one

Comment: @Paulie_D I need them to changed dynamically like photo:
1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2

Comment: So? You just set them to span two columns - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36470038/how-to-exclude-the-first-item-in-a-flexbox-wrap

Answer (score 1):

I guess this code will help you.

```
 .parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
    grid-row-gap: 0px;
    }
    
.div1 { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 7; }
.div2 { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2; }
.div3 { grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3; }
.div4 { grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 3; }
```

There are some CSS grid generators that can help you with structure, like this one:
https://grid.layoutit.com/

Comment: Thanks, it's useful, but i am trying to understand elementor schema and use it