# nth-of-type don't show anything after 2

Tags: css

how can I say that only the first thing should be shown?

```
.box:nth-of-type(2) {
    display:none;}
```

makes only the second thing hidden, how can I say "hide everything except the first one"?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12289853/3284463

Comment: that's so complicated though!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `:not` selector with `:first-child`.

```
.box:not(:first-child){display:none;}
```

**OR**

You can select the first element using the `:first-child` Selector and give it the properties of `display:block;`. And add the `display:none;` property to the other elements

```
.box:first-child{display:block;}
```