# How to give spaces between < a > tags which are wrapped in a div

Tags: css

How to give spaces between `<a>` tags which are wrapped in a div?

```
<div class="sideMenu"> 
  <a href="#" > A </a>
  <a href="#" > B </a>
  <a href="#" > C </a>
</div>
```

css:

```
.sideMenu{
  padding: 50px;
}
```

Comment: What kind of particular spacing? Do you mean vertical or horizontal or something else?

Comment: horizontal spacing

Comment: Please show [any attempts you've made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and [any research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) as well.

Comment: rather than padding, margin will be good. For just space visibility both works but if a tag has background color, there won't be space between background wrap of each a tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to space the children of a div with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507014/how-to-space-the-children-of-a-div-with-css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply margin-right property for all a tags inside your div.

```
.sideMenu a {
  margin-left: 5%; 
/* use %, em, px. % and em are recommended. */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a CSS rule:

```
.sideMenu a {
   margin-right: 10px;
}
.sideMenu a:last-of-type {
   margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector `.sideMenu` gives padding to the `div`, not the `a` elements inside it. To select the `a` elements, the descendant selector `.sideMenu a` or child selector `.sideMenu > a` can be used.

For example:

```
.sideMenu a {
  background: cyan;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrintoul/38hb9gyp/)

Comment: @Deke could you expand on this? [Here's another fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrintoul/q5rd6me2/) using this technique. Perhaps the padding is being overridden by another rule.

Answer (score 0):

You might also use the non-breaking space character (depending on what you need ie. a space vs some space):

`<div class="sideMenu"> 
  <a href="#" >&nbsp;A&nbsp;</a>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Added `.sideMenu a` css that might help you.

```css
.sideMenu {
  padding: 50px;
}

.sideMenu a{
    line-height: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="sideMenu"> 
  <a href="#" > A </a>
  <a href="#" > B </a>
  <a href="#" > C </a>
</div>
```